# Angular/Ionic : Json data working on device?

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello my app work's on browser, but some stuff I can't see in emulator/phone.
for example :

`<img ng-src="{{DefinitionCtrl.checking.feedbackMessage.img}}" class="image-definition">`

the data is loaded from JSOn, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you display `DefinitionCtrl.checking.feedbackMessage.img` value before your `img` element, like this:

```
<span ng-bind="DefinitionCtrl.checking.feedbackMessage.img" />
```

You can see if your variable is defined :)

Comment: It's strange : 
a) Everything works on Browser, but on phone not.
b) When i make normal path like src="..." it works.
c) It gives me, a right path, so variable is defined.
d) I add  img (2 times) and the one with src work's the one wit {{}} not working.